# Optaplanner's benchmark warm up - OutOfMemory

Tags: java, optaplanner

While trying to test the solution's solvers using a benchmark configuration, I encounter the follow exception :

```
2021-12-22 15:24:37.328  WARN 22684 --- [    Test worker] c.o.b.i.D.singleBenchmarkRunnerException : The warm up singleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_Currently used_0) with random seed (null) failed.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2021-12-22 15:24:37.329  WARN 22684 --- [    Test worker] c.o.b.i.D.singleBenchmarkRunnerException : The warm up singleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_Currently used_0) with random seed (null) failed.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2021-12-22 15:24:37.330  WARN 22684 --- [    Test worker] c.o.b.i.D.singleBenchmarkRunnerException : The warm up singleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_Currently used_0) with random seed (null) failed.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1207)
    at myrostering.solver.PEC.LambdaExtractorEC9F24820AB70C5865CE63ED29F967E9.apply(LambdaExtractorEC9F24820AB70C5865CE63ED29F967E9.java:69)
    at myrostering.solver.PEC.LambdaExtractorEC9F24820AB70C5865CE63ED29F967E9.apply(LambdaExtractorEC9F24820AB70C5865CE63ED29F967E9.java:1)
    at org.drools.model.functions.Function1$Impl.apply(Function1.java:35)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaReadAccessor.getValue(LambdaReadAccessor.java:42)
    at org.drools.core.rule.Declaration.getValue(Declaration.java:258)
    at org.drools.core.rule.Declaration.getValue(Declaration.java:253)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.BindingEvaluator.getArgument(BindingEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluator$InnerEvaluator.getArgument(ConstraintEvaluator.java:242)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluator$InnerEvaluator$_2.evaluate(ConstraintEvaluator.java:309)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluator.evaluate(ConstraintEvaluator.java:124)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaConstraint.isAllowedCachedLeft(LambdaConstraint.java:187)
    at org.drools.core.common.SingleBetaConstraints.isAllowedCachedLeft(SingleBetaConstraints.java:132)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:178)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doNode(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:89)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:591)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:558)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:385)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:345)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:181)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:139)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:235)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:91)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:753)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:700)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:692)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1225)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1200)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsScoreDirector.java:105)
```

Here is the test class I ran:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class, MyRosterProperties.class})
public class SolverBenchmarkTest {

    private PlannerBenchmarkFactory benchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            "myrostering/benchmark/benchmarkSolverConfig.xml");

    @Autowired
    MyRosterGenerator myRosterGenerator;

    @Test
    public void benchmarkBasicRostering() {
        MyRoster mr = myRosterGenerator.createMyRoster();
        PlannerBenchmark benchmark = benchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark(mr);
        benchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser();    
    }

}
```

Here is the benchmark configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark/benchmark.xsd">

    <benchmarkDirectory>local/benchmark/data/my-roster</benchmarkDirectory>
    <parallelBenchmarkCount>AUTO</parallelBenchmarkCount>
    <warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>30</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>

    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <solver>
            <!-- This part of the solver configuration must be the same as the one used by the planner, otherwise, the benchmark test is pointless -->
            <moveThreadCount>4</moveThreadCount>
            <solutionClass>myrostering.domain.MyRoster</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>myrostering.domain.Assignment</entityClass>
            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <scoreDrl>myrostering/solver/myRosteringScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>
            <termination>
                <!-- Adding this secondsSpentLimit (contrary to no limit set for the planner) to avoid the benchmark running for too long -->
                <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
                <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0medium/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
            </termination>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>STRONGEST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Currently used</name>
        <solver>
            <localSearch>
                <unionMoveSelector>
                    <moveListFactory>
                        <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                        <moveListFactoryClass>
                            myrostering.solver.move.factory.ChangeMoveFactory
                        </moveListFactoryClass>
                    </moveListFactory>
                    <moveListFactory>
                        <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                        <moveListFactoryClass>
                            myrostering.solver.move.factory.SwapMoveFactory
                        </moveListFactoryClass>
                    </moveListFactory>
                </unionMoveSelector>
                <acceptor>
                    <entityTabuSize>5</entityTabuSize>
                    <simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>15000hard/10medium/1000soft</simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>
                </acceptor>
                <forager>
                    <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
                </forager>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
</plannerBenchmark>
```

Also, I'd like to add that we run the solver.solve() without an issue - even if the dataset is quite large (150 to 300 Mo for the file containing the solution when serialized). So I'm a bit surprised when the benchmark fails on warm up...

EDIT:

I've changed the configuration for these two parameters :

```
<parallelBenchmarkCount>1</parallelBenchmarkCount>
...
<secondsSpentLimit>600</secondsSpentLimit>
```

But I still got the following exception :

```
2022-01-03 10:53:49.850  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl  : Start creation of KieBase: defaultKieBase
2022-01-03 10:53:49.909  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl  : End creation of KieBase: defaultKieBase
2022-01-03 10:54:32.585  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver       : Solving started: time spent (41506), best score (-38295462hard/38260medium/3640soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4), random (JDK with seed 0).
2022-01-03 10:54:33.611 ERROR 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.core.impl.solver.thread.ThreadUtils  : Multithreaded Local Search's ExecutorService didn't terminate within timeout (1 seconds).
2022-01-03 10:54:33.611  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.h.thread.MoveThreadRunner        : Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread (0)'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
2022-01-03 10:54:33.611  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.h.thread.MoveThreadRunner        : Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread (1)'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
2022-01-03 10:54:33.611  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.h.thread.MoveThreadRunner        : Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread (2)'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
2022-01-03 10:54:33.611  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] o.o.c.i.h.thread.MoveThreadRunner        : Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread (3)'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
2022-01-03 10:54:33.612  INFO 21696 --- [nchmarkThread-1] .c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase : Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (42533), best score (-38295462hard/38260medium/3640soft), score calculation speed (0/sec), step total (0).
2022-01-03 10:56:00.115  WARN 21696 --- [    Test worker] c.o.b.i.D.singleBenchmarkRunnerException : The subSingleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_Currently used_0) with random seed (null) failed.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3480)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:454)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
    at be.myrostering.solver.move.factory.MySwapMoveFactory.createMoveList(MySwapMoveFactory.java:50)
    at be.myrostering.solver.move.factory.MySwapMoveFactory.createMoveList(MySwapMoveFactory.java:30)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.factory.MoveListFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge.constructCache(MoveListFactoryToMoveSelectorBridge.java:72)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.SelectionCacheLifecycleBridge.phaseStarted(SelectionCacheLifecycleBridge.java:51)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:37)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:50)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:37)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:50)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.phaseStarted(LocalSearchDecider.java:94)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.phaseStarted(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:92)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.phaseStarted(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:141)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:82)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:192)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:122)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

2022-01-03 10:56:00.603  INFO 21696 --- [    Test worker] o.o.b.impl.report.BenchmarkReport        : Generating benchmark report...

VERSION_2_3_31
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_2_3_31
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.BenchmarkReport.writeHtmlOverviewFile(BenchmarkReport.java:828)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.BenchmarkReport.writeReport(BenchmarkReport.java:318)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:311)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:100)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:424)
```

On a final note, it appears that the problem might not be linked to Optaplanner (because the out-of-memory is triggered in MySwapMoveFactory) - if so, I'll close this post. But it would be still odd that it works when running the solver but not the benchmark...

Comment: Let's start with the obvious - do you have enough memory? You are using 4 move threads, with AUTO parallel benchmarks. That will be quite a few threads, (16?) each with its own solution.

Comment: Configuration is the same as the one used for solving the exact same solution. (4 threads) As noted in the doc : "The parallelBenchmarkCount is always limited to the number of available processors. If it's higher, it will be automatically decreased." Also in the doc : "AUTO: Let Planner decide how many benchmarks to run in parallel. This formula is based on experience. It's recommended to prefer this over the other parallel enabling options. " So I assumed it was safe to use those parameters. Maybe it is not?
Finally, I'm running this on a  i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz processor, with 32Go memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`MoveListFactory` scales badly, consuming a lot of memory and cpu.**

Some kind of moves have billions of possible moves. For example a 3 swap on 10000 shifts has 1 trillion moves. That doesn't fit into a few GB RAM and it takes ages to generate.

Use a `MoveIteratorFactory` instead and don't generate a list of moves, but generate them **Just In Time**, just like the default selectors do. See docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, given the fact that we use two of these factories and that one of them create a list with 7+ million moves, that explain our issue.

Answer (score 1):

Increase memory, for example with VM option `-Xmx4g`

Also note that parallelBenchmarkCount AUTO currently doesn't take into account that moveThreadCount is not NONE. So your benchmarks will not be accurate, because if you have 16 cores, parallelBenchmarkCount AUTO will resolve to 8. With moveThreadCount 4 (+ 1 solver thread), you'll be using 32+ cores but only have 16 cores. This probably should be reported as an issue in optaplanner's jira for parallelBenchmarkCount AUTO.

Comment: I already did increase memory for the benchmark test (up to 16go - but did not change a thing). Thanks, I'll then try by changing these configuration and report back.

Comment: Still got an error (out of memory) after my changes, the difference is that I changed the configuration and that the error appears after the warm-up this time. See post's edit.

Comment: Run while wathcing it with VisualVM. If the heap memory shows sign of a memory leak, do a memory profile twice to figure out what's leaking. Optaplanner doesn't have any (known) leaks, but it could scale up a small memory leak in your model very easily...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, for now, I'm able to run the benchmark by decreasing the  Move list size created by one of the MoveListFactory. But I'll definitely try to find a memory leak in our model.

Comment: That's the problem the, see other answer